# What is the preferred sql server column definition to use for a LINQ to SQL Version property?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008

We are using the `IsVersion` property on the `ColumnAttribute` on a property in a LINQ to SQL class for optimistic concurrency checks. What should the column definition be in the database?

Currently we are using

```
version_number int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1)
```

Do we need Identity? Can we get LINQ to SQL to update the version number for us? The only issue with Identity is that every row has a different number. We'd like to see the number increment by 1 when the row is updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "version" of a row should be updated every time the row gets modified - the unique ID of a row definitely does *not* qualify for that! (this typically is set once and never changes).

What you're looking for is a `TIMESTAMP` or `ROWVERSION` in SQL Server - it used to be called `TIMESTAMP`, but since it's really just a 8-byte binary "counter" and has nothing to do with time and/or date (other than the fact it's monotonically increasing over time), the SQL Server team will be calling it `ROWVERSION` from now on.

This is a data type that gets updated by SQL Server internally - you cannot set or insert a value into such a field yourself. It's guaranteed to change every time the row changes, so you can use it to detect something has changed in your data.

See the [MSDN docs on rowversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx) or read the [Understanding TIMESTAMP (ROWVERSION) in SQL Server](http://aspalliance.com/1785) article on ASP Alliance.

Comment: @marc_s - I think you mean monotonically increasing. Although monotonously is not inaccurate.

Comment: @Mike Two: you're absolutely right :-) Fixed my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a Timestamp data type in your database tables. This will translate to a System.Data.Linq.Binary type in your entities.

With the Timestamp data type, SQL Server will automatically create and increment this value for you.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use a real timestamp if the data does not change too often (I do that a lot in financial applications, but I can guarantee different timestamps), or a simple counting column.

Comment: @TomTom - I prefer a simple counting column, but I can't get LINQ to SQL to update it for me when I set the `IsVersion` property to true.

Comment: Same here, and no - LINQ has no provision for this. The class, though, can handle that itself in the change logic. Not tooo nice... but well.... better than nothing.